# edit query error with foreign key constraints

Tags: php, mysql

ok here it is. i have a table product with foreign keys from product_sizes,brands,categories, and suppliers table. when i display the products table to a html. i use JOIN so that the data displayed in the products table is not the id's of the foreign keys but rather its corresponding names.. i have no problem with the query in regards of adding data. my problem is when i try to edit the data with my edit query. , it prompts me an error about foreign key constraint. i will post my products table and also my edit query. here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_name` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `product_color` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `product_description` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `product_standardPrice` double default NULL,
  `product_unitPrice` double default NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) default NULL,
  `brand_id` int(10) default NULL,
  `size_id` int(10) default NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `brand_id` (`brand_id`),
  KEY `supplier_id` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `size_id` (`size_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `product_name`, `product_color`, `product_description`, `product_standardPrice`, `product_unitPrice`, `category_id`, `brand_id`, `size_id`, `supplier_id`) VALUES
(1, '12', '12', '12', 212, 1, 3, 22, 3, 1),
(2, '2', '2', '2', 2, 2, 4, 23, 2, 2);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`brand_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `suppliers` (`supplier_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `product_sizes` (`size_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and here is my edit query:

```
if(isset($_POST['editproduct'])){
$product_id=$_POST["product_id"];
$product_name=$_POST["product_name"]; 
$product_color=$_POST["product_color"]; 
$size_name=$_POST["size_name"]; 
$product_description=$_POST["product_description"]; 
$brand_name=$_POST["brand_name"]; 
$category_name=$_POST["category_name"]; 
$supplier_name=$_POST["supplier_name"]; 
$product_standardPrice=$_POST["product_standardPrice"]; 
$product_unitPrice=$_POST["product_unitPrice"]; 
$sql = "UPDATE products SET 
product_name='$product_name'
,product_color='$product_color'
,size_id='$size_id'
,product_description='$product_description'
,brand_id='$brand_id'
,category_id='$category_id'
,supplier_id='$supplier_id'
,product_standardPrice='$product_standardPrice'
,product_unitPrice='$product_unitPrice' 
WHERE 
product_id='$product_id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: products.php");
}
```

please help me with my problem. i need to solve these asap.

and here is my products.php page in case you need it

```
<!--- DISPLAY TABLE -->
<form method="post">
<table class="sortable" id="mytable" align="center">
<tr>
<th><strong>Product #</strong></th>
<th><strong>Product Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Color</strong></th>
<th><strong>Size</strong></th>
<th><strong>Description</strong></th>
<th><strong>Brand</strong></th>
<th><strong>Category</strong></th>
<th><strong>Supplier</strong></th>
<th><strong>Standard Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Unit Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>
<?
include ("conn.php");
$sql="SELECT * 
,product_sizes.size_name as size_id 
,brands.brand_name as brand_id
,categories.category_name as category_id
,suppliers.supplier_name as supplier_id
FROM products 
JOIN 
    product_sizes on product_sizes.size_id=products.size_id 
JOIN 
    brands on brands.brand_id=products.brand_id 
JOIN 
    categories on categories.category_id=products.category_id 
JOIN 
    suppliers on suppliers.supplier_id=products.supplier_id 
ORDER BY product_id";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['product_id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['product_color']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['size_id']; ?> </td> <!---- HOW TO DISPLAY NAME RATHER THAN ID? --->
<td><? echo $row['product_description']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['brand_id']; ?></td>  <!---- HOW TO DISPLAY NAME RATHER THAN ID? --->
<td><? echo $row['category_id']; ?></td>  <!---- HOW TO DISPLAY NAME RATHER THAN ID? --->
<td><? echo $row['supplier_id']; ?></td>  <!---- HOW TO DISPLAY NAME RATHER THAN ID? --->
<td>P <? echo $row['product_standardPrice']; ?></td>
<td>P <? echo $row['product_unitPrice']; ?></td>
<td><a href="forms.php?product_id=<? echo $row['product_id']?>&mode=editproduct">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</table> 
</form>
<!--- END -->
```

and heres my editform

```
########### EDIT PRODUCT FORM

if($mode=="editproduct") 
{
$product_id=$_GET["product_id"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$product_id=$row['product_id'];
$product_name=$row['product_name'];
$product_color=$row['product_color'];
$size_id=$row['size_id'];
$product_description=$row['product_description'];
$brand_id=$row['brand_id'];
$category_id=$row['category_id'];
$supplier_id=$row['supplier_id'];
$product_standardPrice=$row['product_standardPrice'];
$product_unitPrice=$row['product_unitPrice'];
} ?>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<form method="post" action="forms.php">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><strong>Edit Product</strong></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<? echo $product_id ;?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_name" value="<? echo $product_name ;?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Color</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_color" value="<? echo $product_color ;?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Size</td>
<td>
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM product_sizes ORDER BY size_id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=size_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value=$nt[$size_id]>$nt[size_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_description" value="<? echo $product_description ;?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brand</td>
<td>
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY brand_name ASC";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=brand_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value=$nt[brand_id]>$nt[brand_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name ASC";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=category_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value=$nt[category_id]>$nt[category_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Supplier</td>
<td>
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM suppliers ORDER BY supplier_name ASC";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=supplier_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value=$nt[supplier_id]>$nt[supplier_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Standard Price</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_standardPrice" value="<? echo $product_standardPrice ;?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Unit Price</td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_unitPrice" value="<? echo $product_unitPrice ;?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="editproduct" value="Save" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<? }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the ongoing discussion in the comments, I'd like to suggest some more general advice:

1. Take away the quotes around the numerical variables in the Update string (e.g., change `size_id='$size_id'` to `size_id=$size_id`).
2. Print the UPDATE string to the browser so you can see exactly what you're asking the database to do.
3. If the JOINS could be causing trouble, try subqueries or even separate queries for the labels (at least as a test).
4. Update only the fields that differ from the saved. Shouldn't really have to do this but one advantage is that you could try just changing the local columns.
5. [new] Change `SELECT *, tab2.foo as bar,...` to just `SELECT *` (while keeping the joins, etc).

Comment: changing the code to "size_id=$size_id" as what you have said gave me more problem. i am not good at programming so please bare with me. if you have the time or anyone helpful enough i have uploaded the files to mediafire. please check if you have the time to. here's the link http://www.mediafire.com/file/dk90ggstcgh1ktd/database.zip

Comment: OK, got the files. May not go through everything but this does make things easier. I notice now that you have "SELECT *, product_sizes.size_name as size_id ..." so that size_id is fetched twice with two different definitions (id and text). Same for some other fields of course. I need to leave now but I'll look for more later.

Comment: Have now added suggestion #5. This was probably making your script update use the label text to update the id fields. Asking for those extra fields was unnecessary since the "*" gets the fields from the joined tables too.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing edits on the labeled fields seems error-prone (spelling). If you have a manageable number of categories (eg, suppliers), you could use drop-down list with the readable names as the labels and id numbers as the values.

Comment: yes my edit form is in <select> tags. thats why i use JOIN in my products.php page so that names would be displayed in the table rather than its ids.. i'll edit my post and add my edit form. please check it out.

Comment: Use associative arrays ("foobar" => 4) to populate the select tags. See http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4555 for an example.

Comment: still cant get the point though. i have no problems populating my select with mysql data. the problem is that i cant edit values of tha foreign key even though the reference table i am using to has the right values for editing.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Let's try again. Did you check that you have Update privileges? I don't think you get that automatically just because you have Insert privileges.

Comment: update priveleges from where? sorry im not good at any of these.. i can update other tables with no foreign keys. also, i can update this table we are talking to before i used the join query in the products table.. as you can see. i used join so that when i display the products table in a datagrid i see the size name not the size id. thats my problem now, after i used join to be able to see the size name instead of the size id, then these error come up.

Comment: The usual method to check privileges is with "show grants" (possibly with "for username"). That's not always so readable or complete so I'd suggest "SELECT user, host, select_priv, insert_priv, update_priv FROM mysql.user;" where you could add a WHERE with the name in the connection string and the tables you care about.